# TypeScript function parameter signature - allow arrow function, disallow class method

Tags: typescript, lambda, function-signature

Say that I have this class that wraps some other library:

```
class A {
    method(callback: () => void): void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and this one using it:

```
class B {
    a: A;

    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
    }

    do(): void {
        this.a.method(this.doLater);
        this.a.method(() => this.doLater());
    }

    doLater(): void {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Both of the calls  inside `B.do()` compile, but the first one fails at runtime because of lost `this` context when it tries to call `doLater()`. Understandable. Not much I can do about that, but I'd like to be able to write the `A.method()` signature so that you are forced to use an arrow function at the call site, since I can't modify the library code. Is that possible?

I'm using TypeScript 2.5.2 and `--noImplicitThis` is enabled

Comment: You cannot express that requirement with TS type system.

Comment: Which part exactly is the library code? Is this `A` class part of it?

Comment: @NitzanTomer nope, I own `A`. Think of that being the wrapper of the library code.

Comment: As @zerkms wrote there's no way for you to restrict this in typescript, you can change the `A.method` to receive another (optional) `thisArg` param and then bind the callback. Then it should be clear that the passed in callback should be either bound already (using `bind` or arrow function) or you can pass the extra param.

Comment: @NitzanTomer yeah, that's actually what I'm doing now as a workaround. OK, thank you all!